# Typoscript replace text with images

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I want to do a simple countdown on my site which uses the below code.

constants:

```
lib.countdown.date = 1293814800
```

Setup :

```
lib.countdown = COA_INT  
lib.countdown {  
  10 = TEXT  
  10.cObject = TEXT  
  10.cObject.data = date:U  
  10.cObject.wrap = ({$lib.countdown.date} -|)/86400  
  10.prioriCalc = intval  
  10.wrap = | 
}
```

The design I have been given means I need to use images for the numbers, but I can't work out how to convert the text to images.  Is there a way this can be done via GIFBuilder or another method?  Or should I approach this a different way?

Comment: Just shift the `TEXT` one level down and use an `IMAGE` object instead.

Comment: You can find examples in the documentation (RTFM!): http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/8/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have had a look already at this and can generate the image but can't seem to generate a particular image depending on the value of the number.  Is there any other demo's that you have seen out there?

Comment: What you you mean with depending on the value of the number. You can generate any text and print it on an image.